# MATLAB: Adjusting the x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, signals

so I have multiple signals on a graph on matlab, however I just want to superimpose these signals with an x- axis from 0 to 3 without chopping off parts of the signal. What commands would I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`axis()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) or [`xlim()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) functions after plots completed. These functions dont change the original range of the signal. They adjust the way to display it. You can see the rest of signal using "Pan" on the figure.

```
% // plots

axis([0 3 -inf inf])

% // xlim([0 3]);    % // Or you can use this instead of axis
```